# Find the constant term in the expansion of...

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

How can we find the term independent of $x$ in the expansion of,

$(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+4x^{\frac{1}{3}}+4)^5\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}+\dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}+x^{\frac{1}{3}}+1}\right)^{-9}$

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The expression is equal to (use some algebraic identities):
$$\frac{(x^{1/3}+2)(x-1)^9}{x^3}=2\binom93(-1)^6+\text{other terms with non-zero powers of x}$$

---

Further Hint:
$$(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=(x^3-1)$$

Comment: Yes, the same at the same time !! When I see monsters, I know (look at my age !) that there must be a simple trick. Happy New Year !

Comment: @AlKhwarizmi. ADG and I gave the same answer !

Comment: Well... I was not being able to simplify the equation to $\dfrac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x}+2\right) (x-1)^9}{x^3}$

Comment: Okay, Now I am getting the constant term $9\choose9$$+$$9\choose3$$(-1)^6$, please help

Comment: we need to find constant term in $\frac{(x^{1/3}+2)(x-1)^9}{x^3}$ or the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(x^{1/3}+2)(x-1)^9$; since the first bracket doesn't give any $x^3$ but only a non- integer term which when combined with a integral term term of second would not give $x^3$ so only choice remains $2$ from bracket 1 and coefficient of x^3 from bracket 2, and as the termof $x^k$ from second bracket is $\binom 9kx^k(-1)^{9-k}$, we're done. @AlKhwarizmi

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}+\dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}+x^{\frac{1}{3}}+1}=\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x}+2\right) \sqrt[3]{x}}{x-1}$$ $$x^{\frac{2}{3}}+4x^{\frac{1}{3}}+4=\left(\sqrt[3]{x}+2\right)^2$$ $$(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+4x^{\frac{1}{3}}+4)^5\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}+\dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}+x^{\frac{1}{3}}+1}\right)^{-9}=\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x}+2\right) (x-1)^9}{x^3}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

**Happy New Year**

Comment: Happy New Year to you too...

Comment: same! I think the saying goes "intelligents think alike"